# Child component not displaying records from Parent record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller, aura-iteration

I am passing the results from Parent component to Child component but the results are not displayed for some reason. I have gone through many example codes and it seems I have done everything correctly. Can someone please help me with this issue?

Parent Component:

```
<aura:attribute access="public" type="Engage__c[]" name="Recs" />
```

Parent Component attribute is set in the helper.js with the results:

```
component.set("v.Recs",response.getReturnValue());
```

Child Component:

```
<aura:attribute access="public" name="datarows" type="Engage__c[]" />
```

Included this in the Parent component:

```
<c:RecList dataRows="{!v.Recs}"/>
```

It displays the results when I iterate all the {!v.Recs} in the Parent Component. It means {!v.Recs} attribute has got all the results correctly.
Just wondering what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lightning components are **case-sensitive**, so either change name of attribute to  `name="dataRows"` or change calling child component

```
<c:RecList datarows="{!v.Recs}"/>
```

Comment: Noted and thanks for your quick help!
@Oleksandr